# Rails default link when using hash sign

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails project on the file located at `myserver/myNewProject/here.html`, and when I have an HTML link like

```
<a href="#test"> ... </a>
```

it jumps back to my old project at `myserver/myOldProject#test`. This is not good, since the old project has nothing to do with the new project.

This is probably because I copied over some code from my old project, but I don't know which part is causing this. How can I correct this behavior?

Comment: Are you using the `link_to` helper? If so, please post how you're invoking it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `:anchor` attribute in the `link_to`:

`<%= link_to('some link', posts_path(:anchor => 'test'))`

Will generate a link like:

`<a href="/posts#test">some link</a>`

See the docs for all the options `link_to` takes:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html